# Uasort with array giving undefined index

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, usort

I've got the following array as an example

```
array(3) {
["date"]=>
    array(6) {
    [0]=>
    string(19) "2014-03-12 00:00:00"
    [1]=>
    string(19) "2014-03-12 08:30:00"
    [2]=>
    string(19) "2014-03-10 08:00:00"
    [3]=>
    string(19) "2014-03-11 08:00:00"
    [4]=>
    string(19) "2014-03-11 08:00:00"
    [5]=>
    string(19) "2014-03-11 17:00:00"
}
["data"]=>
    array(6) {
    [0]=>
    string(115) "
2 tests were booked
"
    [1]=>
    string(316) "
08:30am
Matamata Class 1 R & F
"
    [2]=>
    string(319) "
08:00am-04:00pm
Truck Course
"
    [3]=>
    string(328) "
08:00am-03:30pm
Trade Ed Rot Class 2
"
    [4]=>
    string(326) "
08:00am-03:30pm
Trade Ed Tga Class 2
"
    [5]=>
    string(330) "
05:00pm-08:00pm
Tauranga Truck Course
"
}
["ad"]=>
    array(6) {
    [0]=>
    int(1)
    [1]=>
    int(0)
    [2]=>
    int(0)
    [3]=>
    int(0)
    [4]=>
    int(0)
    [5]=>
    int(0)
}
}
```

And this is my function:

```
function date_compare($a, $b) {
    return strtotime($a['date'])>strtotime($b['date']);
}
```

And I'm trying to sort all the data by date/time using the following uasort `uasort($dayEvents, 'date_compare');` but I'm getting `Notice: Undefined index: date` for each one. I've searched for about an hour now with no luck, can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**
Ok so I've changed my array structure, but it's still not sorting the data by date?

Start array:

```
$dayEvents = array();
$dayEvents['output'] = array();
```

And it is assigned like so:

`$dayEvents['output'][] = array('date' => $dateStamp, 'data' => $dataOutput, 'ad' => $allDay);`

Example output:

```
array(1) {
["output"]=>
  array(6) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      ["date"]=>
      string(19) "2014-03-12 00:00:00"
      ["data"]=>
      string(115) "
2 tests were booked
"
      ["ad"]=>
      int(1)
    }
    [1]=>
    array(3) {
      ["date"]=>
      string(19) "2014-03-12 08:30:00"
      ["data"]=>
      string(316) "
08:30am
Matamata Class 1 R & F
"
      ["ad"]=>
      int(0)
}
    [2]=>
    array(3) {
      ["date"]=>
      string(19) "2014-03-12 08:00:00"
      ["data"]=>
      string(319) "
08:00am-04:00pm
Truck Course
"
      ["ad"]=>
      int(0)
    }
    [3]=>
    array(3) {
      ["date"]=>
      string(19) "2014-03-12 08:00:00"
      ["data"]=>
      string(328) "
08:00am-03:30pm
Trade Ed Rot Class 2
"
      ["ad"]=>
      int(0)
    }
    [4]=>
    array(3) {
      ["date"]=>
      string(19) "2014-03-12 08:00:00"
      ["data"]=>
      string(326) "
08:00am-03:30pm
Trade Ed Tga Class 2
"
      ["ad"]=>
      int(0)
    }
    [5]=>
    array(3) {
      ["date"]=>
      string(19) "2014-03-12 17:00:00"
      ["data"]=>
      string(330) "
05:00pm-08:00pm
Tauranga Truck Course
"
      ["ad"]=>
      int(0)
    }
}
}
```

The statement to sort it:

```
if(count($dayEvents['output'])>1) {
    uasort($dayEvents, 'date_compare');
}
```

And the function itself:

```
function date_compare($a, $b) {
    return strtotime($a['date']) > strtotime($b['date']);
}
```

I'm no longer getting the undefined index error, but it's still not sorting by date? Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `$a['date']` is an array.

Answer (score 1):

Well `ad` is just an array with zeros...

Are you trying to sort the date array?

```
<?php

$dayEvents = array(
    "date" => array(
        "2014-03-12 08:30:00",
        "2014-03-10 08:00:00",
        "2014-03-11 08:00:00",
        "2014-03-11 08:00:00",
        "2014-03-11 17:00:00"
    ),
    "ad" => array(
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0
    )
);

function date_compare($a, $b) {
    return strtotime($a) > strtotime($b);
}

usort($dayEvents['date'], 'date_compare');

var_dump($dayEvents);
```

[Output](http://codepad.org/EjCLsUkd):

```
array(2) {
  ["date"]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    string(19) "2014-03-10 08:00:00"
    [1]=>
    string(19) "2014-03-11 08:00:00"
    [2]=>
    string(19) "2014-03-11 08:00:00"
    [3]=>
    string(19) "2014-03-11 17:00:00"
    [4]=>
    string(19) "2014-03-12 08:30:00"
  }
  ["ad"]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    int(0)
    [1]=>
    int(0)
    [2]=>
    int(0)
    [3]=>
    int(0)
    [4]=>
    int(0)
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I'm trying to sort the data by time, I've updated my example to what it will actually output. I don't think I've built my array properly but not quite sure. :)